# Web3 - Best practive for calling onlyOwner view from backend

Tags: web3js, contract-invocation, nodejs, contract-debugging

from my backend, I want to call the following **onlyOwner** function from my deployed smart contract:

```
function isValid(address _address)
        public
        view
        onlyOwner
        returns (bool){
        // ... validating and returning bool
    }
```

I implemented a working solution on my backend, where I add the contract owner's private key temporarily to the wallet  like so:

```
// prepare wallet before calling onlyOwner function
web3.eth.accounts.wallet.add(OWNER_PRIVATE_KEY);
const account = web3.eth.accounts.wallet[0].address;

// create contract instance and call onlyOwner function
let contract = new web3.eth.Contract(abi, CONTRACT_ADDRESS);
const isValid = await contract.methods
          .isValid(address)
          .call({ from: account });
```

Now, cause the private key, is the most sensitive data, i'm wondering, is this a good practice of calling the **onlyOwner** function or is there a better way of calling a **onlyOwner** function? My fear is, that some exception could be thrown and is revealing the private key or something. Again the whole code is running on a backend, so nothing to exploit on client side, but I think you understand my fear.

Maybe important to mention, this function could be called 100 times a second, but because it's a read only function and no transactions, from my knowledge right now, this should be no problem, right?

Would be great, if someone give me feedback on this.

Comment: `onlyOwner` is a [function modifier](https://solidity-by-example.org/function-modifier/) not a function.

Comment: I know that, but I wanted to highlight it in the text. Should I make it bold instead of code style? I made an edit

Answer (score 1):

This should be fine as long as you make sure your private key doesn't leak anyway to the front-end. But I'm not sure why you'd need a `onlyOwner` modifier for a view function. Even though the function contains a modifier, anyone can look up the state of the contract (for example using `eth_getStorageAt`) and compute the response `isValid` function might return. The modifier is primarily used to restrict write operations on the contract as anyone can technically perform read by looking at the contract state.

Comment: I didn't know that. I thought onlyOwner is also valid for view functions. Is it easy to bypass this by using eth_getStorageAt? I used the isValid function as a extra security step, so this would be actually important.

Comment: A view function just lets you read the contract state. With `onlyOwner` other contracts can't read the state if that's what you are looking for. But it can be read off-chain using `eth_getStorageAt`.

Comment: Understand. Thanks for this letting me know about eth_getStorageAt. I will take a look, how this function works. Just one last question, which is a bit off hand from the origin question I posted, but maybe you can quickly help me here.

Comment: As I said the isValid function is like a secuirty step, but only temporarily. So would I remove the ownerOnly modified, how easy or even possible is it for someone to know that the isValid function exists / what is does / structure of function, when the contract is not verified / visible on etherscan?

So my Plan B would be, to verify the contract after this temporarly phase, so that the code is not visible for everyone. Does this make sense as a plan b in security?

Comment: Can you explain what kind of security you are trying to implement? I can try to suggest good patterns accordingly?

Comment: Basically, the user is calling getValidToken() on his side, which returns based on the msg.sender a token. So in web3 he would pass his address. The user is sending this token to the backend. My plan was, that the server is calling the isValid(address) function and is comparing, if the returned token is the same, like we got from the user.

Comment: As I said this is just a temporarly security solution, cause I know, that basically everyone could call getValidToken() from web3, if someone wants to mess around. But during a temporarly phase, this seemed ok for me in terms of security, cause its not that easy for someone with a not revealed contract to get used to all the flow.

Comment: pbsh, I hope you understand, what I want to achieve